# Python - how can I split a list of string to get the unique splits in original order

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, split

I have the following list of string:

```
diabo_faves = [
  {"Description": "Local-Standard-Office"},
  {"Description": "Local-Standard-Extended},
  {"Description": "Local-Standard-247"},
  {"Description": "Direct-Standard-Office"},
  {"Description": "Direct-Standard-Extended"},
  {"Description": "Direct-Standard-247"},
  {"Description": "Premium-Standard-Office"},
  {"Description": "Premium-Standard-Extended"},
  {"Description": "Premium-Standard-247"},
];
```

And I want to get the following result from it in JSON (Keeping the order):

```
Filters: [
  [
    "Local",
    "Direct",
    "Premium"
  ],
  [
    "Standard"
  ],
  [     
    "Office",
    "Extended",
    "247"
  ]
]
```

However, when I use this method:

```
def get_filters(self, favorites, seperator = "-", ignores = []):

    favorites = self.prepare(favorites, ignores)

    steps = []
    for fave in favorites:

        filters = fave.split(seperator)

        for index, filter in enumerate(filters):

            try:
                steps[index].add(filter)
            except IndexError:
                steps.append(set([filter]))

    return [list(step) for step in steps]
```

I get the result in the incorrect order like this:

```
Filters: [
[
    "Premium",
    "Local",
    "Direct"
  ],
  [
    "Standard"
  ],
  [     
    "247",
    "Extended",
    "Office"
  ]
]
```

How can I change my method to keep the original order that was specified? "Local", "Direct", "Premium" etc..

Comment: What does `prepare()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import izip

splitted_values = izip(*(x['Description'].split('-') for x in diabo_faves))
print [list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)) for x in splitted_values]
#[['Local', 'Direct', 'Premium'], ['Standard'], ['Office', 'Extended', '247']]
```

Here `splitted_values` contains all the column values:

```
[
 ('Local', 'Local', 'Local', 'Direct', 'Direct', 'Direct', 'Premium', 'Premium', 'Premium'),
 ('Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard', 'Standard'),
 ('Office', 'Extended', '247', 'Office', 'Extended', '247', 'Office', 'Extended', '247')
]
```

Then we pass each of these to `OrderedDict.fromkeys` to only get the unique items in the order they were seen first. If `OrderedDict` is not available to you(introduced in Python 2.7) then you can use the [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertoools.